# How can i set label Font in C# with multiple checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, forms, fonts, label

I am newbie in C sharp, I already tried a lot of settings, but didn't helped. 
I would like to create form with a button and 3 checkboxes and a label.
If i check, the first checkbox set my label to bold
when i click "go" button.

After when i check, the second checkbox set my label to italic, and bold
when i click "go" button.

Finally when i check, the third checkbox set my label to italic, and bold and underlined.

It works, but when i uncheck my checkboxes, I would like to remove these font settings? How can I remove them?

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbunderline.Checked == true)
    {               
        lbltext.Font = new Font(lbltext.Font.Name, lbltext.Font.Size, lbltext.Font.Style | FontStyle.Underline);
    }

    if (cbitalic.Checked ==true )
    {
        lbltext.Font = new Font(lbltext.Font.Name, lbltext.Font.Size, lbltext.Font.Style | FontStyle.Italic);
    }

    if (cbbold.Checked==true)
    {
        lbltext.Font = new Font(lbltext.Font.Name, lbltext.Font.Size, lbltext.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the styles, always start with the base style, then only add in the ones that are checked:

```
    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // start with the base font, then add in each selected style
        Font fnt = new Font(lblFontSample.Font.FontFamily, lblFontSample.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
        if (cbBold.Checked)
        {
            fnt = new Font(lblFontSample.Font, fnt.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
        }
        if (cbItalic.Checked)
        {
            fnt = new Font(lblFontSample.Font, fnt.Style | FontStyle.Italic);
        }
        if (cbUnderline.Checked)
        {
            fnt = new Font(lblFontSample.Font, fnt.Style | FontStyle.Underline);
        }
        lblFontSample.Font = fnt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        if (cbunderline.Checked == true)

        {               lbltext.Font = new Font(lbltext.Font.Name, lbltext.Font.Size, lbltext.Font.Style | FontStyle.Underline);
        }

        if (cbitalic.Checked ==true )
        {
            lbltext.Font = new Font(lbltext.Font.Name, lbltext.Font.Size, lbltext.Font.Style | FontStyle.Italic);
        }

        if
            (cbbold.Checked==true)
        {
            lbltext.Font = new Font(lbltext.Font.Name, lbltext.Font.Size, lbltext.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This won't **REMOVE** the styles when the boxes are unchecked, though.

Comment: this is my problem :(

Comment: Just realized this post should have been part or your original question description.  I've edited it to include this.  As such, please delete this comment.